# img tag not loading Google drive image public link in NextJS

Tags: typescript, image, next.js

Good Day,

I wrote my portfolio website, uploaded all necessary images on my Google Drive and used the public url as the src value in the `<img />` tag.
When I wrote the website newly, the images were loading without any issue but currently the images aren't loading anymore both in development and production mode, and I can't seem to figure out the issue

Some steps I took in debugging the issue;

- Whenever I call the image directly from the `public` folder, it loads properly but whenever I load the same image from my Google Drive using its' public url, it doesn't load.
- I checked to make sure the image on my Google Drive still exist and that its' access permission is still public
- I checked to make sure I had an images configuration for google drive domain set properly in my `next.config.js` file even though I'm using `<img />` and not `<Image />`.
- Whenever I use `<Image />`, it loads properly but whenever I use `<img />`, it doesn't load at all. Going with this solution means that I have to change all `<img />` in my source code to `<Image />` and also compulsorily input the width and height value for all the images that would be used in my website including the ones that would be loaded from the database, which is kind of a long-cut solution
- I surfed the internet for possible cause/solutions and found non

Here is the link to the website https://favoursyre.vercel.app and here is the link to the source code https://github.com/favoursyre/portfolio_frontend.git

Please can someone help me with the cause and possible solution to this issue?

Thanks and Regards